# How to properly timeout a DB connection in java

Tags: java, database, performance, jdbc, timeout

I've developed a client-server application of which the server connects to a database. Each time a client connects, a client thread is being started and upon requesting data from the db an instance of my DB class is being made. Every time there is a request I'll establish the connection between server and database and at the end of the DB request close the connection again. To improve performance I'd like to not simply establish and close the connection for every DB operation. Rather I'd like to have like a timeout that starts when the client requests something from the DB and if the client doesn't request any more data within let's say 5 minutes after that, the connection times out. So I'd gain performance as establishing the connection currently takes up by far the most time of the process and on the other hand, I'd free up resources in a reasonable amount of time of the user being inactive.

The problem is that I can't really think of good design on how to properly implement this timeout. The timeout needs start ticking as soon as data has been sent back to the client and needs to reset when a new request is made. Maybe solving this problem is really easy but as I don't know how to approach this timeout (or rather timeouts in general) I'd be very grateful for any suggestion be it a specific implementation, general design tips or pointing me towards a 
good documentation regarding this issue.

Comment: You should probably get a ready-made connection pool, instead of trying to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I'll have a look into this topic then :)

Comment: Definitely use an existing connection pool. Read the [HikariCP/wiki](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki) for how complicated it can get.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that. I'm already studying Baeldung's blog post on this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling

Comment: What is your database? It is the same vendor or many?